# Android Layout for large physical screen start from 42 inch or above

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to develop app for all `available screen sizes` as well some custom screen like `Monitor for displaying via HDMI`.

I have given weight to manage layout on small physical screen size device like 7 inch or 10 inch and its working fine but not on higher then this.

I have done for known OEM android devices using layout folders .But its now working on some custom screen like `Monitor having screen size 42 inch or 70 inch`.

Can you tell me how i can manage very large physical screen size.

`EDIT`
It is not working properly on large physical size .
Let me add some on this
I have given weight to views to take re[image]quired dimension on UI. As on small physical size device suppose if i have given weight 1 to label and 3 to its Edittext . So on small physical size it oaky As we don't have much space on screen to scale but  on large physical size devices it has scaled to its level as per given weight.
I am also attaching image of my problem as reference. It is very large for screen size around 90 inch

`EDIT 2` I know it should work like that when working with weight but i want to manage layout for such situation

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Please see edit and screenshot for refrence

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html) there's the official Android guide on what changes you need to do to your layouts to support large screens like TVs.

> EDIT 2 I know it should work like that when working with weight but i want to manage layout for such situation

Create a layout (if you don't have one) for the TV screen size (take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) very informative guide by Android on how to create layout folders for different screen sizes and densities). In that folder, copy-paste your layout xml file and change the weight ratio to the desired one, or better, set the width of the EditText to wrap_content to avoid the large white space.